# How to insert a quickchart.io api generated image into laravel dompdf

Tags: laravel, charts, dompdf

I want to use https://quickchart.io/ API to generate chart images and I want to insert them into a Laravel PDF report created with barryvdh/laravel-dompdf. I am creating the URL for the quickchart.io API and it works correctly, if I put it in the browser's address bar the image of the chart is returned just fine. But I can't insert it into the PDF report because I get this error: "Image not found or type unknown". And that is quite understandable because the URL doesn't simply contain an image name like "my-image.png". I am trying to use this markup in the PDF view: `<img src="{{ $ga_UsersCpcChartUrl }}" alt="google analytics chart">`. I already set the line: `"enable_remote" => true` inside the dompdf config file. What shall I do to fix this?

Comment: Hi @valicos, did you find a solution  for this?

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to work around this is to add a URL parameter to the end of the QuickChart URL that identifies it as an image.

```
<img src="{{ $ga_UsersCpcChartUrl }}&f=.png"
```

This will help programs that rely on file extension.

If that doesn't work, I'd probably have to see your `$ga_UsersCpcChartUrl` to help debug further.